# Why does the JScrollPane not appear around my JTextField?

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane, jtextarea

I'm pretty new to GUI but I'm trying to create a simple version of notepad and would like scroll bars to appear around the text area. However, I'm not sure why it isn't appearing.

```
public class NutPad extends JPanel {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    JFrame frame = new JFrame("NutPad");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.getContentPane().add(new NutPad(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
    frame.setSize(500,300);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

private NutPad() {
    add(makeTextAreaPanel());

}

private JPanel makeTextAreaPanel() {
    JPanel textAreaPanel = new JPanel();
    textAreaPanel.setSize(100,100);

    JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(20, 60); //15,43
    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(textArea); 

    textAreaPanel.add(scrollPane,BorderLayout.CENTER);
    textAreaPanel.add(textArea);

    return textAreaPanel;
}

}
```

Thanks

Comment: Remove `textAreaPanel.add(textArea);` , your textArea is already added to the scrollpane .

Comment: Okay cool, thanks! Was unsure if it did that already. Doesn't solve the problem though :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're going to use the `BorderLayout.CENTER` constraint, then the container needs to have its layout set to `BorderLayout`.

Also you don't need `textAreaPanel` since you can just add the `scrollPane` straight into your `NutPad` panel.

```
private NutPad() {
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    add(makeScrollPane(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
}

private JScrollPane makeScrollPane() {
    JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea();
    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(textArea);

    return scrollPane;
}
```

Now your text area will fill the frame and the scrollbars will appear when the text takes up more than the available space.

Hope that helps :)

Comment: wow thanks a lot! I decided to make a panel since I will add other bits on.

Comment: No problem. Glad it helped. If you would like to you can click the tick next to this answer to accept it. You will get points for this and so will I :) You can only mark one answer as the accepted answer.